# Function Templating mixed with Overloading

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

So I want to create a function that reads data from text files into a various matrices.
This first is an `Eigen` matrix, where you access elements with parentheses.
E.g. `mat(1,2)`. The second is types like `vector<vector<T>`, where `T` can be an `int`, `double`, etc. Obviously they are accessed with square brackets.

Now I need to create a template for both situations. `Eigen` has many matrix types (`MatrixXd`, `SparseMatrix` etc.), and `vector<vector<T>>` could have many types `T`.

However, **how do I ensure that the template function for `Eigen` won't be called when what I really want is the template function for `vector<vector<T>>`?**

I know that overloading takes precedence over templating, but they are both templated!
**What should I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a partial specialization* for the nested-vector case, and the general case for the various Eigen classes, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(vector<vector<T>>& mat) {
    // code that uses mat[x][y]
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T& mat) {
    // code that uses mat(x,y)
}
```

(* Yes, I know the pedants will point out that, technically speaking, this is not "partial specialization" but "partially ordered function overloading".)

Comment: So I don't understand why the first templated function will be called when we apply to a `vector<vector<T>>` object. Is it because it is defined first? It seems like the first function is "more specialized" or something to a `vector<vector<T>>`: Is this why? What rule resolves the ambiguity?

Comment: What you've written does seem to work though. I wrote a third template function for `vector<T>`, and it seems to decide correctly between the 3 options. I just don't want to be using this without knowing how it works and have it go wrong one day.

Comment: Yes, the more specialized overload wins. The detailed rules can be found in the section tagged  [temp.deduct.partial] in the C++ standard (section 14.8.2.4 in the current draft; it may have different numbers in earlier editions). In ambiguous cases (e.g. if there were two arguments, specialized in different ways in different overloads), you can sometimes get a compile error because the compiler can't unambiguously pick one "most specialized" version, but in this case it's always clear which one is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept a C++11 solution, what about using SFINAE checking if the type `T` can support `T()(0U, 0U)` or `T()[0U][0U]` ?

This should work if `T` doesn't support both operations.

The following is a working example (where `bar` substitute `Eigen`)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
auto foo (T & mat) -> decltype( mat[0U][0U], int() ) 
 { return 1; }

template <typename T>
auto foo (T & mat) -> decltype( mat(0U, 0U), int() ) 
 { return 2; }

struct bar
 {
   void operator() (std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<std::vector<int>>  m1;
   bar                            m2;

   std::cout << foo(m1) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << foo(m2) << std::endl; // print 2
 }
```

If you have to work with a template class that support both `[0U][0U]` and `(0U, 0U)` (see `baz` in the following example) you can give the precedence to one version or another passing (by example) an `int` value and receiving an `int` in the preferred version and a `long` in the other version

See the following code for an example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
auto foo (T & mat, long) -> decltype( mat[0U][0U], int() ) 
 { return 1; }

template <typename T>
auto foo (T & mat, int) -> decltype( mat(0U, 0U), int() ) 
 { return 2; }

template <typename T>
int foo (T & mat)
 { return foo(mat, 0); }


struct bar
 {
   void operator() (std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
    { }
 };

struct baz
 {
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> m;

   std::vector<int> & operator[] (std::size_t x)
    { return m[x]; }

   int & operator() (std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
    { return m[x][y]; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<std::vector<int>>  m1;
   bar                            m2;
   baz                            m3;

   std::cout << foo(m1) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << foo(m2) << std::endl; // print 2
   std::cout << foo(m3) << std::endl; // print 2 
 }
```